# comparison operator in for loop in c++

Tags: c++

Isn't the below code supposed to initialize all the array elements to 0 using the for loop?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    for(int i=0; i==9; i++){
        a[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
164752
6
0
0
-13120
0
-13211
0
0
0
```

Comment: Look closer your conditions

Comment: ok, I'll ask you to state what is meant by `for(int i=0; i==9; i++)`.  What does the middle condition in the `for` statement denote?  And why did you write the second `for` loop conditions correctly, but failed to do so on the first `for` loop?  The `for` loop conditions should be no different for the working loop as the non-working one.

Answer (score 3):

Check here [corrected-code](http://ideone.com/h3HHH0)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int a[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){ // <= i < 10 instead of i == 9
a[i] = 0;
}

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
cout << a[i] << endl;
}

}
```

Comment: The strange thing is that the OP wrote the second `for` loop conditions correctly, which should have been no different than than first `for` loop.  Maybe the OP is not getting the full picture of what the conditions in a `for` loop means.

Comment: I agree with you. Maybe, the user wanted to write `i<= 9` and a typo resulted in `i==9`

Answer (score 1):

No, because the comparison in the for loop is not correct. It just checks if i is 9 at the beginning, which turns out to be false, and hence, the first for loop doesn't execute at all.
The correct condition should be i<=9 (or i<10) instead of i==9, which is what you have written in the 2nd loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Corrected code:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[10];

    for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++)
        a[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a for loop like `for (int i = 0; i == 9; i++)` the second expression (`i == 9` is the condition for **continuing** to run the loop. Since `i` is 0 the first time through the loop, `i == 9` is false, and the loop immediately ends; execution continues with the next statement. Change it to `i < 10`; that way, on the first time through the loop, when `i` is 0, the condition is true, and execution continues. In fact, it continues until `i < 10` becomes false, which happens after the tenth execution of the body of the loop.